# cups-browsed.service causing input/video lag

Tags: cups-lpd

I Have disabled cups-browsed.service with this command:

sudo systemctl disable --now cups-browsed.service

And for my surprise, after that, now i can feel less input/video lag

For my surprise ...

Anyone else can test, so we can really sure it is not placebo?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling this service should not affect input/output lag, as cups-browsed is a service that enables network printing and should not have a direct connection to input/output lag.

Comment: I tried adding lp user to group input, because printer needs sometimes usb connection ...
is it relevant to avoid lookup?

Comment: Not really, it's too little load to be noticeable. Maybe there is a loop in the network? Then there is a chance that it can significantly reduce network bandwidth. You can always ping the website (for a few minutes) and start printing something, if the response time varies greatly, then you can start looking around the web for the problem.

Comment: playing on steam i noticed significantt performance increase by adding lp user into input group, maybe something i cant explain was dropping input/video performance ...